# Ignore sorting of two objects if the two sort object contain a value

Tags: java, sorting, comparator

I am sorting a list using a custom comparator.

```
Collections.sort(list, new DispositionShiftSortComparator(shiftSortComparatorIndex));
```

In the compare function, if any of the two objetc has a cretain value, then I don't want comparator to sort the list in that call.

Function is as follows:

```
           boolean taskStatusObj1 = false, taskStatusObj2 = false;
            long time1 = 0, time2 = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < o1.getValue().getTaskCount(); i++) {
                if (o1.getValue().getTask(i).getObject() instanceof TaskObject) {
                    TaskObject obj1 = (TaskObject)o1.getValue().getTask(i).getObject();
                    if (obj1 != dndTask) {
                        taskStatusObj1 = ((TaskObject)o1.getValue().getTask(i).getObject()).getSafeDataItem(DataKey.DK_TASK_STATE).stringValue() != null ? true : false;
                    }
                }
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < o2.getValue().getTaskCount(); i++) {
                if (o2.getValue().getTask(i).getObject() instanceof TaskObject) {
                    TaskObject obj2 = (TaskObject)o2.getValue().getTask(i).getObject();
                    if (obj2 != dndTask) {
                        taskStatusObj2 = ((TaskObject)o2.getValue().getTask(i).getObject()).getSafeDataItem(DataKey.DK_TASK_STATE).stringValue() != null ? true : false;
                    }
                }
            }
            if (taskStatusObj1) {
                new Date(o1.getValue().getTask(o1.getValue().getTaskCount() - 1).getEndTime());
                time1 = o1.getValue().getTask(o1.getValue().getTaskCount() - 1).getEndTime();
            } else {
                time1 = 0;
            }
            if (taskStatusObj2) {
                new Date(o2.getValue().getTask(o2.getValue().getTaskCount() - 1).getEndTime());
                time2 = o2.getValue().getTask(o2.getValue().getTaskCount() - 1).getEndTime();
            } else {
                time2 = 0;
            }
            if (time1 != 0 && time2 != 0) {
                return -(int) (time1 - time2);
            } else if (time1 != 0 && time2 == 0) {
                return (int) time1;
            } else if (time1 == 0 && time2 != 0) {
                return (int) -time2;
            }
            return 0;
        }
```

In the function I am checking if object is not of type dnd task, don not preform sorting. Can any one help me where I am wrog in my approach.

Comment: A comparator does not sort, it just determines which of the two values is smaller.

Comment: is your `time1` and `time2` always positive?

Comment: What is that certain value?

Comment: Done. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the details so I'd go solve it like this:

1. write a `Comparator` that returns `0` if any of the object contains that certain value.
2. use a [stable sorting method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm#Stability), i.e. that won't change the order of equal items.

### The comparator

```
public class DispositionShiftSortComparator<DispositionShif> {

    @Override
    public int compare(DispositionShift shift1, DispositionShift shift2) {
        if ((shift1 != null && containsCertainValue(shift1)) || (shift != null) && containsCertainValue(shift2)) {
            return 0;
        }
        // ... do the rest as you did
    }
}
```

### The right sorting algorithm

[`Collections.sort()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort(java.util.List,%20java.util.Comparator)) is guaranteed to be stable. It's the easy part:

> public static  void sort(List list,
>               Comparator c) Sorts the specified list according to the order induced by the specified comparator. All
>   elements in the list must be mutually comparable using the specified
>   comparator (that is, c.compare(e1, e2) must not throw a
>   ClassCastException for any elements e1 and e2 in the list). This sort
>   is guaranteed to be stable: equal elements will not be reordered as a
>   result of the sort.

Comment: It wont be transitive. Imagine 3 object a, b, c. One of them have this property (let it be b). Then a = b and b = c then a = c, which mean that all object must be equal.

Comment: Right. I'm afraid it's a specification issue.

Comment: It is not. If you make that special object equal to each other and less then all other object it still be transitive.

Comment: OP wrote this: "if any of the two objetc has a cretain value, then I don't want comparator to sort the list in that call.".  Literally, it makes no sense, i.e. the comperator does not sort a list. So, if we try to guess what he really wanted, then we're on our own. My guess is that he does not want to move object that have that certain value. Even if it makes the sorting non-transitive.